# Flutter "Unable to checkout version branch for version number" when trying to upgrade to specific version

Tags: ios, macos, flutter

My Xcode project is using Flutter to make some functions. Now my team told me to upgrade to version `v1.12.13+hotfix.7`. I'm in v1.9.1 and I'm trying to run this command like in Flutter homepage and getting this error:
[image]
[image]

Previously I have used this command to upgrade from v1.7 to 1.9.1 and it's work normally. Because I don't know how to use Flutter before and I just work with native language only so I don't know how to fix this. Can you guys help me to fix it? I cannot ask my team because we're not work in the same place and it take a lot of time to wait for a response via instant messages.

Answer (score 2):

**If you read this answer carefully I'm pretty sure you'll fix this issue.**

```
unable to checkout version branch for version 1.12.13+hotfix.7.
```

this error means that the particular version of flutter you want to use in is not present in the repository.

you can verify this by running `flutter version` command, this command will list out all the version present as of now. if you don't find the version you want to checkout then you will have to pull latest tags from the.

**Solution**

1. Go you location where you've installed flutter or where you might    have extracted the flutter zip(if you've installed through the .zip  file).
2. Run command `git fetch --tags` to fetch all the tags from remote    repository.
3. Run command `git checkout tags/1.17.0` to checkout your desired version.
4. Run command `flutter --version` this might take couple of minute to get update.

After this you will be able to update your desired version of flutter